# How to check existence of a deep property

Tags: javascript

Is there any better solution for following code:

```
 if (response && response.responseJSON && response.responseJSON.message) {
        //code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is fine.  It looks a little ugly, but it makes it clear what's going on.  If you REALLY wanted to, you could probably put the full expression in a `try-catch` block, but that would be poor practice and harder to read/maintain.

I imagine you want something like Groovy's "[Safe Navigation Operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator%28?.%29)", so you could do:

`if (response?.responseJSON?.message)`

but Javascript does not have anything like this.

Comment: Wouldn't he get the same result by just writing: if(response.responseJSON.message)?

Comment: No, if response.responseJSON didn't exist, it would throw a console error with "Cannot find propery/object message of undefined" or something along those lines.

Comment: @dzny, yeah like @Kodlee Yin said, if `response` or `responseJSON` is null or undefined, it will throw an error.  That's where you *could* put it in a try-catch, but the current approach is preferred/typical.

Comment: I see. So @PHPst should accept yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a helper function:

```
Object.prototype.deepExist = function(attPath){
    var o = this,
        path = attPath.split(".");

    for (var i=0; i<path.length; i++){
        o = o[path[i]];
        if (!o) {
            return false;   
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

usage:

```
if (response.deepExist("responseJSON.message")){
    //code
}
```